# How to click on skip button of youtube in selenium

Tags: selenium

In HCL interview they asked us to automate skip button of advertisement in youtube using selenium. can anybody help me how to automate this ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable code sample in your post.

Comment: Youtube's player is using HTML5, as well as all the components that appear  above it. You break the logic down into three scenarios,

1) A pre-skip button exists, you want to wait until it's changed state and click that then ensure the video is played as expected by checking the player's state.
2) You are able to skip right away, so you press this button and ensure the video is played as expected using the player's state.
3) The ad cannot be skipped, so you wait a maximum time you hardcore or try and fetch from the overlay and ensure the video players as expected.

Answer (score 3):

For Firefox:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import threading
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/root/Downloads/geckodriver")
url="https://www.youtube.com"
driver.get(url)
```

Search on Youtube:

```
youtube_search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/form/div/input")
youtube_search.send_keys("Latest Videos") #Searches for
#Click Search
clickButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/form/button")
clickButton.click()

assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source

skipAd = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath for next /html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[5]/button")

def skipAdFunction():
    threading.Timer(3,skipAdFunction).start()
    if(skipAd.is_enabled() or skipAd.is_displayed()):
        skipAd.click()

skipAdFunction()

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a method skipADD2 to automate skip button of advertisement in youtube,
If video does not have Skip Add button present it will raise an    exception which is caught in first catch block and
// Step 1: Wait for the Page to load
// Step 2: Check the Visibility of the skip add button if it is false then it will go in the catch block and gracefully terminate the program
// Step:3 If it True then perform click operation on skip ad

```
public void skipADD2() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    WebElement videoAdUiPreSkipButton = null;
    WebElement skipaddbutton = null;
    log.info("*****************************************Printing Information In The begining ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
    try {
        videoAdUiPreSkipButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='videoAdUiPreSkipButton']"));
        log.info("*************VISIBILITY OF THE ELEMENT IS ************************* " + videoAdUiPreSkipButton.isDisplayed());
        if (videoAdUiPreSkipButton.isDisplayed() == true) {
            log.info("*************Getting Text from the Pre text Box in the begining************************* " + videoAdUiPreSkipButton.getText());
            WebElement videoAdUiPreSkipButtonFirstDiv = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='videoAdUiPreSkipButton']//div[1]"));
            log.info("*************Getting Text from the FIRST DIV in the begining*************************** " + videoAdUiPreSkipButtonFirstDiv.getText());
            // WebElement videoAdUiPreSkipButtonSECONDDiv = driver
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            log.info("*************VISIBILITY OF THE ELEMENT 'YOU CAN SKIP ADD ' IS AFTER WAITING MORE THAN 5 SECONDS " + "************************* " + videoAdUiPreSkipButton.isDisplayed());
            skipaddbutton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='videoAdUiSkipContainer html5-stop-propagation']"));
            log.info("*************VISIBILITY OF THE ELEMENT FOR SKIP ADD BUTTON" + "************************* " + skipaddbutton.isDisplayed());
            log.info("*************VISIBILITY OF THE ELEMENT FOR SKP ADD BUTTON " + "************************* " + skipaddbutton.getText());
            skipaddbutton.click();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } else {
            log.info("+++++++++++++video Doesn not have Skip Add button and It is Stopped in Second Catch Block +++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.info("+++++++++++++video Doesn not have Skip Add button and it is not monextized and I am terminating Program in First excepion Block +++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        driver.navigate().refresh();
        skipADD2();
    }
```

I used **driver.navigate().refresh();** to refresh the window if the Ad is not present.