# How to click the 'skip ads' button in youtube using selenium in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to create a Python3 script using selenium that opens a youtube video, then skips the add. I tried using this:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="skip-button:8"]/span/button')\
            .click()
```

But it would just pause the video, because I think the mouse needs to be hovering the button before clicking it. Here is the class that will do this:

```
class MusicPlayer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Safari()
        self.driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suia_i5dEZc")
        sleep(10)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="skip-button:8"]/span/button')\
            .click()
        sleep(260)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to click on skip button of youtube in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43953551/how-to-click-on-skip-button-of-youtube-in-selenium)

Answer (score 1):

```
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ytp-ad-skip-button-container')
button.click()
```

Is the way I figured to do it.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to use WebDriverWait to wait for the element until it is clickable

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suia_i5dEZc")


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20*60)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='skip-button:6']/span/button")))

element.click()
```

Comment: `from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`